# UINavigationBar missing image on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar, iphone-5

I'm working on a proyect that was built a while ago for iOS 4.2.
I had to work on resizing a few views for iPhone 5 etc. Everything works perfectly except for a NavigationBar that is missing the background image.

The only warning I got when I tried compiling this on iOS 6 was:

```
@interface UINavigationBar (HomeBrokerNavigationBar) 

UIView * topItemHeaderView;

Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol.
```

I commented that line out and wrote the same line on top of @interface so now I don't get any compile errors but the NavigationBar shows without an image.

This is not my proyect so I don't want to mess too much with the controllers. I was just supposed to update the views. Has anyone had this kind of issue?
This is how things look:

```
UIView * topItemHeaderView; 

@interface UINavigationBar (HomeBrokerNavigationBar) 

//UIView * topItemHeaderView; //This caused an error so I commented it and placed the line outside. 

- (void)layoutNavigationBarBackground;
- (void)layoutNavigationBarShadow;
- (void)setTopItemTitle:(NSString *)title andSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle;
- (void)setTitleForStockWithShortName:(NSString *)stockShortName andLargeName:(NSString *)stockLargeName;
- (void)setFirstActionButtonWithImage:(NSString *)imageName forTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action;
- (void)setSecondActionButtonWithImage:(NSString *)imageName  forTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action;
- (void)setThridActionButtonWithImage:(NSString *)imageName  forTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action;

- (void)setActionButtonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImage:(NSString *)imageName forTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action;


@end
```

and the .m file:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

self.topItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

if(!self.hidden)
{
    self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.003922 green:0.137255 blue:0.313726 alpha:1.0];
    
    [self layoutNavigationBarBackground];
    [self layoutNavigationBarShadow];
}
}


- (UIView *)topItemHeaderView {
return topItemHeaderView;
}

- (void)layoutNavigationBarShadow {

    CAGradientLayer * navigationBarShadow;

    navigationBarShadow = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];

    navigationBarShadow.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, 0, self.frame.size.width + 20, 20);

    CGColorRef topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;

    CGColorRef bottomColor = [self.tintColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor;

    navigationBarShadow.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor, (id)bottomColor, nil];

    [navigationBarShadow autorelease];


    [self.topItemHeaderView.layer addSublayer:navigationBarShadow];
}
```

So it's just the bgHeader.png not showing up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a category of UINavigationBar to set the background image? Use the UIAppearance API.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Alternatively, if you just want to set the background for one UINavigationController, do the following:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Edit ---

As other things are being used in the category, I suggest that you subclass UINavigationBar instead and thus subclass UINavigationController replacing the navigationBar property with the subclass UINavigationBar.

Alternatively, as you cannot add ivars to a category, you must create a property. Properties work the same in the .h method, but differently with the setter and getter methods when it comes to categories.

In order to set and get properties in categories, you must implement the `objc_getAssociatedObject()`, and `objc_setAssociatedObject()`.

```
@interface UINavigationBar (HomeBrokerNavigationBar) 

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView * topItemHeaderView;

@end

static const void *TopItemHeaderViewKey = &TopItemHeaderViewKey;    
@implementation UINavigationBar (HomeBrokerNavigationBar)

@dynamic topItemHeaderView;

- (UIView *)topItemHeaderView {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, TopItemHeaderViewKey);
}

- (void)setTopItemHeaderView:(UIView *) newHeader {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self,TopItemHeaderViewKey, newHeader, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Comment: Problem is the category does a lot more stuff. If I use that line in the app delegate. The image then covers everything else on the bar. The category adds a bunch of buttons and text.

Comment: Actually, adding that line to the app delegate shows the desired color now. But I see 2 navigation bars now. The important one with the buttons on top and a second empty one below it.

Comment: I get "Implicit declaration of function "objct_getAssociatedObject" is invalid in C99... Would you mind a 5 min private chat?

Comment: I get the same error if I copy paste from your code. Funny thing is everything works in the bar. Buttons, text, functionality is perfect, I'm just missing that image...

Comment: You could always just run `[backgroundImage drawInRect:rect];` to your -drawRect method?

Comment: Just tried that... won't do it... I just can't figure out why it works on 4.2 and not here and none of the solutions I find online will draw the image..